# Can't wake up Mac-connected display when in clamshell mode

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake, closed-clamshell

My setup is this:

- MacBook Pro TouchBar Late 2016 (15'')
- a Dell P2415Q display, connected via USB-C → DisplayPort cable
- External keyboard, mouse, connected wirelessly (through dongles/hub/then usb-c cable) + an Apple bluetooth trackpad.
- the MacBook stays in clamshell mode.

For some time now, waking up the Mac using the external keyboard/mouse/trackpad has stopped working, because the display fails to wake up. I have to open the lid for the ext display to show anything (and then close it again).

The Mac itself **does wake up**. If I blindly press a key, type in my password, and press Return, after opening the lid, I will be logged in.

It's the display that won't wake up.

Here's the things I've tried:

- Clean up all the system caches, NVRAM, SMC
- Reset display settings
- Try a different port to connect the display
- Try disconnecting everything else except AC and display cable
- Disable automatic GPU switching
- Disable all kexts (except for Karabiner, which I don't know how to unload. I tried running my Mac in Safe Mode, but, ridiculously, it fails to boot in Safe Mode.)

This little issue drives me absolutely mad. Please advise.

Comment: Is your Bluetooth set to allow waking?

Comment: Yes, Bluetooth is set to wake up my Mac.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I have a LG monitor connected to a MBP 2015 via thunderbolt, keyboard and mouse connected to the USB hub built-in in the monitor. I have to open the lid a bit to wake up the external monitor. The MBP does wakes up when I hit the keyboard though, there is just no signal going to the monitor.

Comment: big news! The latest update for osx (10.13.4) fixed it for me! Anybody else can confirm?

Comment: Confirm, I still have this problem on 10.14.6 (Mojave) I haven't tested any other cables or anything, as I'm far too lazy and it's taken me about a year to even google the problem (and here I am). It's pretty annoying but I just replug the monitor cable and it wakes, rubbish but does the trick

Comment: Had a similar issue with the Samsung m7 monitor with Big Sur (only in usb-c mode with my usb-c iMac, not with hdmi mode with my mini-DP iMac). After long periods of inactivity, the monitor failed to get a signal from the Mac when it was woken up. Fixed the issue for me by scheduling a smart plug to turn on my monitor 15 minutes before the scheduled boot up.